# Error - event points to NULL c#

Tags: c#, events, delegates, threadpool

I'm trying to raisn an event using threadPool in c#.
Problem is, that it points out to me that the Event points to NULL.

```
public class ClientView : IView<string>
{
    event Presenter.func ViewChanged; }
event Presenter.func IView<string>.ViewChanged
    {  add{}            
       remove{} }
     public void ClientConnection()
    {
        while (true) 
        {

            int recv = Client.Receive(data);
            if (recv == 0) break;
            userInput = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            ViewChanged();   //here it crashes because it's null
        }
        Client.Close();
    }


class Presenter {
      private IView<string> view;
      public delegate void func();
      public Presenter(IView<string> view)
    {
        this.options = new Dictionary<string, ICommandable>();
        options.Add("generate", new Option1());
        this.view = view; 

        this.view.ViewChanged += delegate ()
        {
            string[] input = view.GetUserInput().Split(' ');
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(options[input[0]].execute, input);
        }; }
```

I do not understand why the program crashes. my event ViewChanged does not point to NULL because I added the delegates to it.. no?

Answer (score 1):

Your application will crash if no event handler has subscribed. Probably you have received data before before your event handler has been attached.

Try changing `ViewChanged()` to `ViewChanged?.Invoke()` if you are using C# 6.0, else you should check if `ViewChanged() != null` before calling it.

Comment: but what is the syntax to add a method to some Event?

Comment: @aviadm71 I am not sure what you mean, but I would recommend that you read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few seasons since I last used C#, so this might not be an "answer," but ... I question the use of the "+=" operator and the fact that you seem to be *calling* "delegate()" instead of referencing its *address.*  That piece of code just doesn't look right to me . . . *(And if I am in error, please add a comment to this reply!)*

Comment: += operator is the way to attach an event handler and delegate() just is a delegate without parameters. Could be without the delegate keyword also as a lambda.

Comment: I therefore yield to Sami's apparent observation that I am *incorrect*.  Thank you for the clarification, and I withdraw my answer.